# Question about iteration

Tags: core-language, iteration

I have the following expression:

```
sol1 = 
  (11 + 3*δ - 11*θ + 4*m*θ - 3*δ*θ - 8*Sqrt[(-(2 + δ))*(-1 + θ)*(1 - θ + m*θ)])/(4 + 4*δ)
```

I want to plug numbers into $ \theta $ that range from $ 0.1 $ to $ 0.9 $.

Does anybody know how to do this more efficiently than using a loop?
I tried to use `For` and `Do`, but I am not sure how to implement the procedure I want correctly.

Comment: For a one-shot use, `ReplaceAll (/.)` suffices: e.g., `sol1 /. θ -> Range[.1, .9, .1]`. If repeated usage is intended, `SetDelayed (:=)` is more appropriate.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ - it is worth pointing out that the reason that `ReplaceAll` works here is that all of the operations used in `sol1` are [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) for that and specify the step you want:

```
Table[sol1, {θ,0.1,0.9,0.1}]
```